# Disabling indexes for a SqlBulkCopy errors out

Tags: .net, sql, indexing, sqlbulkcopy

I'm trying to improve the peformance of a call to [SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(Datatable).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x.aspx)

One of the suggestions I've seen is to temporarily disable the indexes on the table before the call to WriteToServer, and then enable the indexes afterwords.

I disable the table with this statement, `ALTER INDEX 'IndexName' ON 'TableName' DISABLE`

The problem I run into, is after I disable to the indexes and try to perform the write an error occurs with the statement, `The query processor is unable to produce a plan because the index 'IndexName' on table or view 'TableName' is disabled.`

Any ideas on how I can avoid this error or improve the write spends by some other means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You disabled the cluster index, instead of just non-cluster indices. Once Cluster index is disabled, you can not perform DML on table.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. It is indeed a clustered index. Thanks!